# Accessing current row value with lag function

Tags: postgresql, lag, window-functions

I want to calculate the difference between the previous and the current column and make it a new column named `increase`. For this, I'm using the [`lag` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html). The value of the first column is not defined since no previous column exists. I know that a 3rd parameter specifies the default value. However, it depends. For the first row, I want to use the value of another column e.g. the one of `count` from that current row. This assumes that 0 is increased to count for the first row which is what I need. Specifying the column name as 3rd argument for the `lag` function does not work correctly and neither does using 0. How can it be done? I'm getting strange results such as quite a random result or even negative numbers.

```
SELECT *, mycount - lag(mycount, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id, messtime ASC) AS increase FROM measurements;
```

Window functions cannot be nested either:

```
ERROR: window function calls cannot be nested
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data (a dozen rows) and what should be the correct result of the query for this sample data.

Answer (score 1):

There is another issue with your query: So far your results are in random order, so you may think you are seeing problems that don't exist.

Add `ORDER BY id, messtime` to your query to see the rows in order. Now you can compare one row with its predecessor directly. Are there still issues? If so, which exactly?

```
SELECT *, "count" - lag("count", 1) OVER (ORDER BY id, messtime) AS increase
FROM measurements
ORDER BY id, messtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` is a reserved word in SQL. It seems the DBMS thinks you want to nest `COUNT` and `LAG` somehow.

Use another column name or use quotes for the column:

```
SELECT *, "count" - lag("count", 1) OVER
```

Comment: That is not the issue here. Sorry for the confusion